# How to left join to select with statement

Tags: mysql, select

I have some tables:

```
 products
 --------------------------
|p_id|col|col...|...|cat_id|


 colors
  -----------
 |id|p_id|url|
```

I want select apropriate rows from first table after join to this result another column selected by apropiate id.

In other words I select all products on some cathegory and how many colors each product has.

For example

```
select * 
from products p 
where p.p_id = some_number
```

and join to this

```
select count(*) 
from colors c 
where c.p_id = p.p_id
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Left join return all row of left table(products) even row's id are not match of right table. for more info [click here](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-left-join.aspx)

```
SELECT p.p_id, COUNT(*) AS colours_count
FROM products AS p
LEFT JOIN colors c 
ON c.p_id=p.p_id
GROUP BY p.p_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select p.p_id, count(*) as number_of_colours
from products as p
left join colors c on c.p_id=p.p_id
group by p.p_id
```

The `LEFT JOIN` operation guarantees that all rows of table `products` will be returned. Grouping by `p_id`, we get a separate row for each product along with the number of colours each product is associated to.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the LEFT JOIN, but note that this returns a row from the left hand table irrespective of whether there is a matching row on the right hand table. Hence it there is no match or 1 match you will still get 1 row returned. As such if you use COUNT(*) you will get a count of 1.

So get around this you count the occurrences of a field from the right hand table (normally the primary key). Used like this COUNT() returns the count of non null fields, so it will return 0 when there is no matching row on the right:-

```
SELECT p.p_id, 
        COUNT(c.id) AS number_of_colours
FROM products p
LEFT OUTER JOIN colors c ON c.p_id = p.p_id
GROUP BY p.p_id
```